# VBA - Export Sheet as CSV without rounding values in CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a script that exports sheet3 in my excel workbook to a CSV.

Unfortunately, the CSV is now rounding my numerical values.   I've embedded an image of the problem and also the VBA script I'm using.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?

[problem with data changing when saving to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0L7Z.png)

VBA Code that's saving sheet 3 to CSV.

```
Public Sub ExportCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")     'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       'Possibly overwrite without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="\\NJTRDNSV01\X242095$\Desktop\pjw\Output", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: The CSV isn't rounding your values. It's Excel rounding the values when you open the CSV.

Comment: So is it fair to assume the CSV I am saving should be fine?  It literally opens the csv on my screen and saves it , so I'm worried this won't meet the requirements.

Comment: It might help if you open the CSV in Notepad for example, instead of Excel, to see what the actually saved data is.

Comment: Thank you sir for the notepad trick!  That actually confirms the values are fine.  Any general thoughts why the actual saving of the file itself is taking excruciatingly long and often times failing?  I'm definitely glad to see it seems to be working (when it works that is haha).

Comment: I would think programmatically saving it would take just as a long as manually saving it. Assuming the amount of data may have some impact. Other than that, out of ideas.